# Generating "working hours" interval index with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

With pandas we can do something like this:

```py
>>> i1 = pandas.Interval(pandas.Timestamp('2021-08-25 09:00:00'), pandas.Timestam
p('2021-08-25 18:00:00'))
>>> i2 = pandas.Interval(pandas.Timestamp('2021-08-26 09:00:00'), pandas.Timestam
p('2021-08-26 18:00:00'))
>>> ii = pandas.IntervalIndex([i1, i2])
>>> ii
IntervalIndex([(2021-08-25 09:00:00, 2021-08-25 18:00:00], (2021-08-26 09:00:00, 
2021-08-26 18:00:00]],
              closed='right',
              dtype='interval[datetime64[ns]]')
```

This way we get interval index of person's working hours for two days. But it's tedious and not really DRY(imagine creating such index for all working days in month).
The question is if it's possible to do the same stuff but with less code? Maybe with the help of `pandas.interval_range` just like we do with `pandas.date_range`

```
>>> pandas.date_range(date(2021, 1, 1), date(2021, 7, 1), freq='B')
DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-01', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-06',
               '2021-01-07', '2021-01-08', '2021-01-11', '2021-01-12',
               '2021-01-13', '2021-01-14',
               ...
               '2021-06-18', '2021-06-21', '2021-06-22', '2021-06-23',
               '2021-06-24', '2021-06-25', '2021-06-28', '2021-06-29',
               '2021-06-30', '2021-07-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=130, freq='B')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`IntervalIndex.from_arrays`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.from_arrays.html) accepts arrays for the `left` and `right` bounds, so you can generate those bounds with [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html):

```py
in_times = pd.date_range('2021-08-25 09:00:00', '2021-09-25 09:00:00', freq='B')
out_times = pd.date_range('2021-08-25 18:00:00', '2021-09-25 18:00:00', freq='B')

ii = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(left=in_times, right=out_times)
# IntervalIndex([(2021-08-25 09:00:00, 2021-08-25 18:00:00],
#                (2021-08-26 09:00:00, 2021-08-26 18:00:00],
#                (2021-08-27 09:00:00, 2021-08-27 18:00:00],
#                ...
#                (2021-09-22 09:00:00, 2021-09-22 18:00:00],
#                (2021-09-23 09:00:00, 2021-09-23 18:00:00],
#                (2021-09-24 09:00:00, 2021-09-24 18:00:00]],
#               dtype='interval[datetime64[ns], right]')
```

---

Note that by default, these intervals are only closed on the right:

```
# (2021-08-25 09:00:00, 2021-08-25 18:00:00]
```

So add `closed='both'` if desired:

```
# [2021-08-25 09:00:00, 2021-08-25 18:00:00]
```

Comment: And then I can use something like this ```>>> start = pd.date_range('2021-08-25 09:00:00', '2021-09-25 09:00:00', freq='B')
>>> stop = pd.date_range('2021-08-25 18:00:00', '2021-09-25 18:00:00', freq='B')``` and get intervals only for working days. Brilliant, thank you!

Comment: you're welcome! i wasn't aware of a business day `freq` setting, so i learned something as well.